# Instead of `error: any = null`, I need something like `error: ExceptionClass = null`

Tags: javascript, typescript

instead of `error: any = null`, I need something like `error: ExceptionClass = null` for parameter passing(maybe some global exception class ?!).

This is what I did/tried.

The problem is, that `console.error(error);` will not fully print the error text, only the first words(it is not collapsable, like if I would run it without typescript).

The error code:

```
 try
        { //...
        }
        catch (ex)
        {
            world.test( ex);
        }
```

The method which logs  the error:

```
export function test(error: any = null): void
    {

        if (error != null && error.length > 0)
        {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

Instead of `error: any = null`, I need something like `error: ExceptionClass = null`.

How can I acchieve this ?

Comment: javascript `console.error` don't know anything about your typescript `error` variable type at runtime

Comment: @Maxx `error` could be any error ,this is why I have choosen the data type `any`, but this does not seem to be good solution, because I only get some words from that error, instead of everything

Comment: i mean that it's no matter what type you write in typescript for `error` variable, your `console.error` output will be the same

Answer (score 0):

The type you are looking for is [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error):

```
function test(error: Error) {

}
```